# list comprehension change list element

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to modify list element using list comprehension.

```
z=[1,2,3]
z=[z[i]=1 for i in range(len(z))]
```

I want to get

```
z=[1,1,1]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `z = [1 for _ in z]`

Comment: Do you actually want to *modify* the original ``z`` (replacing its elements) or *replace* ``z`` itself with a new list? Are you aware of the [comprehension grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), most importantly that it may only contain *expressions*, not statements?

Comment: then, how can convert my list when I have a certain condition?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change all the variables of a list into the same number, using list comprehension - you're basically creating a new list...
so if that's your intention it should be like this:

```
z = [1,2,3]
z = [1 for x in z]
```

Output:

```
[1,1,1]
```

Comment: Thanks you. Why my code isn't working? Can you explain ?

Comment: z is iterable, you don't need to create a range object with the length of the list

Comment: correct about the iterating over a list , I'll correct my answer. and the reason your answer did not work @lincplushtm is because you tried to iterate over each value and assign a new value to it - that'll be fine using a loop. but list comprehension works differently. it calculates the argument on the left for every element of the object you're iterating and adding it to the list. So what you were trying to do is not calculate anything but change it's value, which prompts an invalid syntax error

Comment: again, you're making the same mistake you did in your question. You are not calculating anything on the left side of the list comprehension, but instead you're trying to force a value change. instead you need to create a new list which the wanted value - and the length of the old list, as I did in my answer. :)

Comment: `z[1] = 1` is a statement, not an expression, and a list comprehension requires an expression in that position.

Answer (score 0):

Use this comprehension:
`z = [z[0] for _ in z]`

This will create a new list with the same length as the old list and will only contain the first element of the old list.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to modify list element using list comprehension.

```
z[:] = [1 for _ in z]
```

or:

```
[z.__setitem__(i, 1) for i in range(len(z))]
```

These will modify the existing list rather than create a new one.  You can see this if you do `print(id(z))` before and afterwards.  Anything starting `z =`  will make `z` point to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify `z` in place, use a `for` loop:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(z):
    z[i] = 1
```

If you want to replace the list itself (not just change the existing list), use a list comprehension:

```
z = [1 for _ in z]
```

You can't use

```
z = [z[i]=1 for i in range(len(z))]
```

because the `x` in `[x for i in y]` must be an *expression*, and `z[i] = 1` is not an expression; it's an assignment statement.